# Definition of a non-linear function

Tags: definition

I would like to use in a proof that $f(x)$ is a non-linear function of $x \in \mathbb{R}$, without assuming that $f$ be differentiable/analytic. I can also use that $f(0)=0$.

Q: What is a convenient definition for this?

If $f$ were differentiable, I could use something along:

> $f(x)$ is non-linear in $x$ if $\exists$ $x_1$, $x_2$ such that $f'(x_1) \neq f'(x_2)$.

The best I can come up with for a non-differentiable $f$ is:

> $f(x)$ is non-linear in $x$ if $\exists$ $x_1,x_2,x_3 \neq 0$ such that $\frac{f(x_2)}{f(x_1)} \neq \frac{f(x_3)}{f(x_1)}$. (There must be at least one $x_1 \neq 0$ since otherwise $f(x)=0$ and thus not non-linear.)

Is there any standard definition out there that I am missing? Any pitfalls I am overlooking?

Edit: By linear function I mean that e.g. $g(x)$ is linear if $\forall x \in \mathbb{R} \quad g(x)=\kappa x$ where $\kappa$ is a constant.

Comment: What do you mean with linear? It preserves linear combinations? It is a line?

Comment: According to your definition, a function $f$ is not linear iff $\forall k \in \mathbb{R}: \exists x \in \mathbb{R}: f(x) \neq kx$ or equivalently, $\not\exists k: \forall x \in \mathbb{R}: f(x) = kx$

Comment: @Math_QED that is good, please go ahead and make this an answer.

Comment: @mts Please, if you are ok, you can accept the answer and set it as solved. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your definition:

> Let $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be a function.
>
> $f$ is called linear, iff there exists $k \in \mathbb{R}$ such that
>   for all $x \in  \mathbb{R}: f(x) = kx$
>
> or written in **quantifier** notation:
>
> $f$ is called linear $\iff \exists k \in \mathbb{R}: \forall x \in 
>  \mathbb{R}: f(x) = kx$

By taking the negation of this definition, we obtain:

> $f$ is not linear $\iff \not\exists k \in \mathbb{R}: \forall x \in
> \mathbb{R}: f(x) = kx \iff\forall k \in \mathbb{R}: \exists x \in
>  \mathbb{R}: f(x) \neq kx$

Answer (score 1):

You could use:

> $$\frac{f(x_2)-f(x_0)}{x_2-x_0} \neq \frac{f(x_1)-f(x_0)}{x_1-x_0}$$

for some $x_2, x_1, x_0$

This should be valid also for general linear function: $g(x)=ax+b$

Answer (score 1):

Since $f$ being linear in the provided sense means that $f(x)=kx$ then you know that $f(a)/f(b)=a/b$ for all non-zero $b$.

You can for instance say that a function $g$ is non-linear if $g(a)/g(b)\not = a/b$ for some pair $a,b$.

(This is precisely the $x_0=0$ case of the other answer, and essentially the same as MathQED's comment.)